# Can I use email address verification in Firebase Authentication but without storing the users in the Users tab?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Can I use email address verification in Firebase Authentication but without storing the users in the Users tab because I store the users in MySQL already?

Second question: is it required to upgrade spark plan to blaze plan to use email address verification?

Comment: No, you don't need to upgrade to blaze plan to use email verification or other any auth providers.

Comment: @VishalBeep Do you know the answer of first question?

Comment: If you are using Firebase auth then all AUTHENTICATED users will be shown in that tab there is no way to change that.

Comment: if my answer resolve your answer then you can accept it by clicking on the ✅ button or upvote it if you think it will help futures devs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to upgrade to blaze plan to use email verification or other any auth providers.

If you are using Firebase auth then all **AUTHENTICATED** users will be shown in that tab there is no way to change that.